# I made a successful AJAX call to the page it's on, but the php won't execute

Tags: php, ajax

Maybe the title doesn't make sense...
When loading page.php, it should return content A. But if a user clicks a button 'B' on page.php, that triggers JS which makes an AJAX call to page.php?param=B.
page.php has php code that's supposed to load content B if it gets requested with ?param=B . In the network tab, it shows that a request was indeed sent to page.php?param=B but the code doesn't run.

What essentially I want to do is display data on page.php sorted based on url param.
I hope this makes sense lol.

```
page.php

<script>
     function sort(selection) {
         //idk y this doesn't work
         let xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
         xmlhttp.open("GET", "/test.php?sortby=" + selection);
         xmlhttp.send();
     }
</script>

<input type="button" onclick=sort(this.value) value="A"></input>


<?php
if (empty($_GET)) {
//query DB for content, don't sort, display

} else if (isset($_GET['sortby'])) {
if ($_GET['sortby'] === 'A') { //query db for content, sort by A and display } 
if ($_GET['sortby'] === 'B') { //query db for content, sort by B and display } 
?>
```

Oh one last note, when I manually enter page.php?sortby=A in the url bar and hit enter, php runs correctly, but when AJAX calls for that same url, php doesn't run.

Comment: Sharing the code will make even more sense.

Comment: Does anything get sent back in the results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point of an Ajax request is that the browser **does not** navigate to a new page, but that the response is handled by JavaScript instead.

You aren't handling the response at all.

You need to wait for the response to load and then do something with it.

```
function loadHandler() {
    const data = this.response; // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/response
    console.log(data);
}

xmlhttp.addEventListener("load", loadHandler);
```

In the above example I'm just logging it to the console. Normally you would want to [insert it into the HTML document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Manipulating_documents).

Generally you wouldn't want to return entire HTML documents from an Ajax request. It is typical to return some data in a JSON structure and use that to update the page.